# Combining states to one vs keeping multiple states to optimize the re-rendering of the component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For a screen component, I'm setting 15 states inside multiple useEffects. But as this is triggering re-rendering all the child components multiple times, I'm thinking of merging some of the states.

```
const MyComponent = () => {

    const [state1, setState1] = useState(null);
    const [state2, setState2] = useState(null);
    const [state3, setState3] = useState(null);
    const [state4, setState4] = useState(null);
    const [state5, setState5] = useState(null);
    const [state6, setState6] = useState(null);
    const [state7, setState7] = useState(null);
    const [state8, setState8] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const {value1, value2, value3, value4} = externalSynchronousFunction1();
        setState1(value1);
        setState2(value2);
        setState3(value3);
        setState4(value4);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (value1 && value2) {
            const {value5, value6, value7, value8} = externalSynchronousFunction2();
            setState5(value5);
            setState6(value6);
            setState7(value7);
            setState8(value8);
        }
    }, [value1, value2]);
}
```

These states will not be updated later. Will this refactor improve the performance of the component?

Answer (score 0):

No, whether the states are separate or combined will have no impact, given the code in the question. Because React can detect that the the `useEffect` callback is running in the context of React, the state updates will be batched if you set state multiple times synchronously. So the component will re-render the same number of times.

(If the external functions were *asynchronous*, on the other hand, it'd be a different story, because the React wouldn't be able to tell that the async callback is running in the context of React, and so would re-render immediately after every state setter is called, rather than waiting and batching re-renders. But luckily, that's not the situation you have here.)

That said, performance is usually *not* important to worry about - much more important, most times in professional software, is *readability* and *maintainability*.